# facebook api: group & livevideos

Tags: facebook, group, live-video

We are using the facebook api to get the comments made on a livevideo published on a group.

The permissions needed are... not clear. We can see the livevideo, but not get the comments and author. Do you know which permissions are required?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: For pages there is `pages_read_user_content` which should allow you to read comments among other things, but I don't see the same thing for groups. I would suggest asking for clarification via https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/

Comment: Thanks @CBroe for your suggestion. I made a request on the Facebook support.